# Algorithm for separating integer into a sum of products of single digit numbers?

Tags: algorithm

This may be a weird question so I'll try being as specific as possible.

> Given an integer *N* (size is irrelevant but for my particular purpose it's up to 255, in case it makes a difference) split up the integer into sums of products of single digit numbers. When I say sums I mean both addition and subtraction. This may or may not be confusing so I'll do my best to clarify with an example or two.

Given the number **73** we first notice the number is prime and therefore the **only single digit divisor** of it is 1, which isn't very useful to us.

Our next step would be to find a close match, for instance `73 = 72 + 1` and we can go from there.

The prime divisors of 72 are 2, 2, 2, 3 and 3; to keep it optimal we can simply write down **8 and 9** instead.

This gives us our final "formula" of `8*9+1` to get to *73*.

---

Obviously I'd love it if the solution could be "the best possible one" for any given number, so I'll give another example that shows where a decision should be made by the algorithm.

Given the number **255** we can obviously do `5*3*17` which leaves us with only one non-single digit prime, which we then need to take apart

**17** can be written down as `8*2+1` so our total is now `5*3*(8*2+1)`. When we get rid of the parentheses we get `8*6*5+5*3`

The problem with this solution is that we could've also written 255 down as `256-1` which would drastically simplify the problem to give us `8*8*4-1` which is obviously the preferred solution.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem before? Any sort of pointers how I might go about this? I'm working in C, but the actual language is not relevant, I'm just itching for a solution to this.

Comment: How is this a coding problem? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: It's an algorithm problem, which were still valid here last time I checked.

Comment: Brute-force?  (And if that's too slow at scale, then one can probably optimise via a dynamic-programming/memoization approach.)

Comment: The easiest algorithm (i.e. least amount of code) is to compute the base 9 representation of the number. For 255, that's `3*9*9 + 9 + 3`

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to explicitly define "best possible one" as simply "solution with the minimum number of terms".